# Trigger event on elements created on the fly at DOM, it's possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete library and apply the behavior to any input with class `typeahead`. That's works for any element that is on the DOM when page loads. I create some elements on the fly by adding some HTML to the DOM using `append` or `clone` or any other jQuery/Javascript function for this purpose and all of them also have the class `typeahead` but behavior isn't triggered on this new elements. how I make this work? I need to trigger the behavior on this new elements too, how? Any advice?

This is the code for trigger the `autocomplete` event:

```
$('#products_forms .typeahead').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: Routing.generate('get_products'),
    paramName: 'filter',
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    noSuggestionNotice: 'Nothing found',
    minChars: 3,
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `typeahead` function after the items are added, ex:

```
var elem = $("<div id='new'></div>");
$("#someContainer").append(elem);
$("#new").autocomplete({});
```

Comment: Doesn't work since I calling the typeahead by class, see the code I added to main post

Comment: Then recall the `typeahead` class.

Comment: @ReynierPM -- Just like above, once you add your elements, call `$(".typeahead").autocomplete()`

Comment: But autocomplete only should start when user type something in that input, the one with focus and only if it haves more than 3 characters, will your suggestion work on this too?

Comment: Yes - on new elements you have to initialize them to the methods you want them to have.

Comment: So I need to repeat the same code (the code I posted on main question) any time I create a new element? What about if I create 100 of them?

Comment: @ReynierPM -- Then create all 100 and call this after. But yes, your new elements don't know about handlers declared before their existence.